# Bootstrap 3.7 modal not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have attached the copies below.
Bootstrap modals isnt working.

[The backdrop emerges but the dialog box doesnt show.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjFPz.png)

[This is my head file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA6Pa.png)

[This is where i call my modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB9KC.png)

Comment: please put the relevant code in here, not just a picture

Comment: @Mak Insane Try moving your `.modal` div outside the `container-fluid`. Hope that will help you, if not please put the relevant code in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Shiladitya Thanks a ton! This worked! and il take care next time to put code over jsfiddle or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you made the same mistake i did several years ago
Call the div of modal just after all your div gets End i.e just before `</body`>
hope this helps you 
And Avoid Posting Screeenhots instead code which will help you for better answer